# C++ 20: Can concepts interface a method?

Tags: c++

To preface this, I wanted an interface, and figured that C++20 had an interface mechanic.  I have never used C++20, and found `concepts` about 2 hours ago.  So the mistake here could be something really simple.

---

Suppose I have an imperative 3rd party library I would like to abstract away because imperative code is messy.

So, I define some very specific function that accepts the 3rd party library class:

```
// The Essence

template<typename Context>
concept ExtensibleContext = requires(Context & context){
  { context.addExtension(char *, bool, void *, uint32_t) };
}

template<ExtensibleContext Context>
void activate_context(Context & context, ThisFeature & thisFeature, ThatFeature & thatFeature){
  context.addExtension(THIS_FEATURE,false,&thisFeature, 0);
  context.addExtension(THAT_FEATURE,false,&thatFeature, 0);
}

activate_context<ThisParticularContext>(context,this,that);
```

```
  // The Actual
  template < typename contextInfo>
  concept ExtensibleDeviceContext = requires(contextInfo & cinfo){
    { cinfo.addDeviceExtension(char * name, bool optional, void * pipe, uint_32 version)};
  };

  template<ExtensibleDeviceContext contextInfo>
  void activate_ray_tracing_vk(contextInfo & cinfo, vk::PhysicalDeviceAccelerationStructureFeaturesKHR & accelFeature, vk::PhysicalDeviceRayTracingPipelineFeaturesKHR & rtPipelineFeature){
  {
    cinfo.addDeviceExtension(VK_KHR_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_EXTENSION_NAME, false, &accelFeature);
    cinfo.addDeviceExtension(VK_KHR_RAY_TRACING_PIPELINE_EXTENSION_NAME, false, &rtPipelineFeature);
    cinfo.addDeviceExtension(VK_KHR_MAINTENANCE3_EXTENSION_NAME);
    cinfo.addDeviceExtension(VK_KHR_PIPELINE_LIBRARY_EXTENSION_NAME);
    cinfo.addDeviceExtension(VK_KHR_DEFERRED_HOST_OPERATIONS_EXTENSION_NAME);
    cinfo.addDeviceExtension(VK_KHR_BUFFER_DEVICE_ADDRESS_EXTENSION_NAME);
    return;
  };
```

However, the compiler shouts at me in despair.  The project is a distributed `cmake` project involving Vulkan, Nvidia, and a pile of source code at the seam between open source and proprietary systems.  The SDK from Nvidia has adopted a build-system-is-code mentality (which is fine -- just have to familiarize).  I have determined the compiler is `g++` with grep:

```
$: mkdir build && cd build
$: cmake ..
...
$: make -n -B | grep g++ | wc -l
220

$: make -n -B | grep nvcc | wc -l
0
```

`g++` on my system (Fedora33) is version `(GCC) 10.2.1`.

```
// The despair (compiler output)
[ 70%] Building CXX object ray_tracing__simple/CMakeFiles/vk_ray_tracing__simple_KHR.dir/main.cpp.o
/home/chris/lab/ray-tracing/vk_raytracing_tutorial_KHR/ray_tracing__simple/main.cpp:57:32: error: expected primary-expression before ‘char’
   57 |     { cinfo.addDeviceExtension(char * name, bool optional, void * pipeFeature, uint32_t version)};

// Specifically
error: expected primary-expression before ‘char’

// which recurs for each of the arguments
error: expected primary-expression before ‘bool’
error: expected primary-expression before ‘void’
error: expected primary-expression before ‘version’
```

I have wasted a lot of time fiddling with this, and what I am trying to discover is whether I am barking up a tree or whether this is possible, and there is some small thing that is incorrect?

If it **should work**, then maybe something in the build is screwing up. `g++ (GCC) 10.2.1`

Comment: "*the compiler (g++) shouts at me in despair.*" :) I sympathize, but it would be a lot more useful if you add the verbatim compiler message as well.

Comment: @Galik limiting verbosity...  so it sounds like things should be possible

Comment: @cigien posted the actual compiler output

Comment: Thanks. Galik is right, you can't use `this` as an identifier. Can you change that and see if the error persists?

Comment: @cigien I posted my actual, it is pretty rough, so I'll mod the "essence" portion to fit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your concept has wrong syntax, it should be:

```
template<typename Context>
concept ExtensibleContext = requires(Context & context, const char *s, bool b, void *p, uint32_t n)
{
  context.addExtension(s, b, p, n);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is a [*compound requirement*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Compound_Requirements), which in your case has the form `{ <expression> }`.
`context.addExtension(char *, bool, void *, uint32_t)` is not a valid expression, because you can't use types in function arguments.  Instead you need to provide values with those types.  You can do this by either adding more parameters to your `requires` like

```
template<typename Context>
concept ExtensibleContext = requires(Context & context, char *arg1, bool arg2, void *arg3, uint32_t arg4){
  { context.addExtension(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) };
}
```

or by using [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)

```
template<typename Context>
concept ExtensibleContext = requires(Context & context){
  { context.addExtension(std::declval<char *>(),
                         std::declval<bool>(),
                         std::declval<void *>(),
                         std::declval<uint32_t>()) };
}
```

[godbolt demo using `std::declval`](https://godbolt.org/z/j95f84).

---

In your case you can omit the curly braces as you don't care about the result type or the expression being `noexcept`, so it simplifies to

```
template<typename Context>
concept ExtensibleContext = requires(Context & context){
  context.addExtension(std::declval<char *>(),
                       std::declval<bool>(),
                       std::declval<void *>(),
                       std::declval<uint32_t>());
}
```

[godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bMc7c5).

Comment: I wish concepts could define interfaces with a more readable syntax.